# Zeppelin doesn't work with external spark - Can not get or update progress

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook

I've installed Zeppelin 0.6.2 and trying to get it working with external spark cluster (2.0.1).

I have my Interpreter setting as follows:

`args

master  121.201.~~.1~~:8080
spark.app.name  Zeppelin
spark.cores.max 
spark.executor.memory

zeppelin.R.cmd  R
zeppelin.R.image.width`

However, when I try spark code, I am getting errors:

INFO [2016-12-16 15:30:28,236] ({pool-1-thread-16} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:1150) - Job 20161215-231306_1684928197 is finished
 INFO [2016-12-16 15:30:28,313] ({pool-1-thread-16} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job paragraph_1481814786923_-1347555476 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpretershared_session1405394754
ERROR [2016-12-16 15:30:30,203] ({Thread-83} JobProgressPoller.java[run]:54) - Can not get or update progress
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getProgress(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getProgress(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:111)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.progress(Paragraph.java:237)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.JobProgressPoller.run(JobProgressPoller.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_getProgress(RemoteInterpreterService.java:296)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.getProgress(RemoteInterpreterService.java:281)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getProgress(RemoteInterpreter.java:370)
    ... 3 more

Comment: URL for spark master is "spark://host:port". Are you sure your spark is running on port 8080? Because it is Zeppelin's default port. spark's default port is 7077.

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks v much. Zeppelin is still not v well documented.